# Magento2 on click any category from menu its give 404 error not showing its products or not going to listing page

Tags: magento2

In Magento2 on click any category from menu its give error page not found and not showing its products or not going to listing page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first to Delete all the Products and Category URLs from a Database table "url_rewrite" and then trying to save each category.

Also, check for the URL suffix from the configuration.

```
Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization
```

Second, run all command

```
rm -rf var/cache
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```